# Energy consumption after removing a part from a PCB

Tags: energy, buzzer

Does removing the buzzer chip from a PCB reduce the energy the PCB uses? Is it save to remove the buzzer?
It's an FMQ.

Comment: What is a FMQ?  Google turns up stuff about quilting.

Comment: Its the label of the device on the pcb that is doint the beep sound. Is it called FMQ Buzzer? https://easyeda.com/component/9391f9d5675b497683b317455643919c

Comment: FMQ-2724 maybe? (Off-topic: the specs of that one on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/IIVVERR-FMQ-2724-Electronic-Buzzer-electr%C3%B3nico/dp/B08LDWDQMV), under "Product information", are hilarious, a must-read.)

Comment: If it is a 1/2 HP buzzer, then yes, I anticipate significant energy savings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buzzer is an electronic element that consumes some current when working. When you remove this element from the board, you automatically breaks its circuit. Imagine light bulb connected to the power supply. When it is connected, current flows and there is current consumption. When you disconnect the bulb, there is no longer current consumption. The same situation is with your buzzer, its circuit would no longer consume current.
If you remove the buzzer from the board there will be less current consumption overall. Not much but always something.